# Is it possible to have multiple outputs (labels) of different sequence length in Tensorflow estimator model_fn?

Tags: python, tensorflow

From Tensorflow v1.2 documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators#constructing_the_model_fn), it states:

> The model_fn must accept three arguments:
>
> features: A dict containing the features passed to the model via
>   fit(), evaluate(), or predict().
>
> targets: A Tensor containing the
>   labels passed to the model via fit(), evaluate(), or predict(). Will
>   be empty for predict() calls, as these are the values the model will
>   infer.
>
> ...

For the case of multi-task sequence learning, there are more than 1 output/label and they could be of different sequence length. Unlike `features`, the argument `labels` is a `Tensor` but not a `dict`, currently I would have to pad zeros with max sequence length for all outputs.

Is there a way to feed labels with different sequence length for different output for `model_fn`?